# QGIS - Missing GDAL Tools plug-in (merging Raster TIFFs of satellite image)

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, qgis-plugins, merge

I am trying to install the GDAL Tools plug-in but it is missing from the Plug-ins list. I am looking to merge multiple Raster TIFFs which make up my satellite image basemap, exported using Atlas, which I can use offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 3x the GDAL tools are located in the Processing Toolbox.

[image]